# Invalid Paypal IPN Response

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Can any body tell me what is error in the following paypal ipn response

`Failed
Response = HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 09 Mar 2012 10:47:38 GMT Server: Apache X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Set-Cookie: cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=HsLFg9XOmQSJyuFKrL6PkJjTED9fh4Zde3UysJ1YnQ1xmilNeg-Y_zLU2wud8XLDahMpf5S7P120pyejIXzBLm%7chW7sdV0qGBjVkzRfcV539j-CN30UarIFBdY8vcVDymTOAxGTgqxzsM2Bz0ulxMIf5UFURW%7c1331290058; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Mon, 07-Mar-2022 10:47:38 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Thu, 04-Mar-2032 10:47:38 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; HttpOnly Vary: Accept-Encoding Connection: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 7 INVALID 0`
??

Comment: I'd not post my Paypal cookies to the web without making sure to log out of my session first.

Comment: With sandbox not so bad, but I'm assuming even a sandbox account can be somewhat abused.

Comment: IPN has nothing to do with cookies. I am not sure what the comments above are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

[The IPN response of INVALID means that you have not provided the ***EXACT*** data, to the server the IPN was sent from, as what was sent to you by that server.](https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmtsrobertg/securing-your-instant-payment-notification-ipn-script)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My problem was: I sent a call from the Sandbox Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator to my real account. It always came back as `INVALID`. After trying to send it to the sandbox server, it worked!
I think paypal works like this is for security reason. I hope my thing works when all credentials are live.